# How to send current page number in MVC4 sorting?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, paging

Hi I have implemented paging in my MVC application and I am implementing sorting facility. When i click on header(ActionLink) i want to sort. This is my pager code.

```
  @Html.PagedListPager(Model.logDetails, page => Url.Action("Index",
new { page, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter, filterdateTime=ViewBag.filterdateTime, filterdocType= Model.doc_typeid, filteredemployeeID = Model.employeeID, filteredcitizenId = Model.citizenId, sortOrder = ViewBag.currentSort }))
                Page @(Model.logDetails.PageCount < Model.logDetails.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.logDetails.PageNumber) of @Model.logDetails.PageCount
```

This is my header where i want sort.

```
 <th>@Html.ActionLink("Label", "Index", new { sortOrder = ViewBag.LabelSortParm, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter, filterdateTime = ViewBag.filterdateTime, filterdocType = Model.doc_typeid, filteredemployeeID = Model.employeeID, filteredcitizenId = Model.citizenId, Page })</th>
```

Here I am having problem with sending current page number back to action method. All the values I am able to send it back to the action method except current page number. Can anyone tell me how can i get and send pagenumber in ActionLink? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the bottom of you razor view page something like it should there for the page navigation. In that case watch out for the parameter called `page`. when ever navigation request has been made from UI, that will pass this current count to Controller Action result method.

```
<!--Grid / Page navigations goes here-->
<br />
Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("List", new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))
```

The same way you should be having your controller logic similar to this. Here also look at the parameter called `page`. which carries the current page number all the time. as we passed from UI. By default it i will be 0 OR 1.

```
    public ViewResult List(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page, ManageMessage? message)
    {
            ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
            ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "Name_desc" : "";
            if (searchString != null) { page = 1; }
            else { searchString = currentFilter; }

            ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

            var company = getComoanyList();

            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "Name_desc":
                    company = company.OrderByDescending(s => s.Name);
                    break;
                default:
                    company = company.OrderBy(s => s.Name);
                    break;
            }

            int pageSize = 10;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
            return View(company.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes it helped. Thanks a lot